# Is the more than one kind of AAC on headphones?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'll be buying a pair of NR headphones for travelling, likely a recent Bose. When reading various reviews, they note AAC support gives you all you need for use with iDevices.

Question: is there more than one sort of AAC for BT? It seems there are a wide variety of the other standards, each one in multiple versions. Is AAC similar, or is there only one AAC for headphones?

Comment: AAC is a lossless music file format.  Bluetooth is a wireless connection technology.  One has nothing to do with the other.  It’s like saying “is there a special gas to drive on the highway?”  Where are you sourcing this info so we can help clarify.  Let’s get you to some good resources.

Comment: @Allan - AAC isn't lossless, that's ALAC, but it does come in various 'flavours' -. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding but yes, has nothing to do with Bluetooth transmission.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin…I meant to say HighRez. I often defer to FLAC over AAC which is lossless and I wrongly confuse the two on that term.

Comment: @Allan - BT is more than just a connection technology, it encompasses many other standards for the data as well, things like SBC and LC3. Due to the relatively low rates available in BT connections, codecs have to choose their data parameters carefully, and that is what I am asking about. AAC can encode at different bit rates, and if it lowers the rate for BT connections then there is the possibility that there are more than one rate that might be used.

Comment: You’re thinking of [Bluetooth profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) like AD2P  or a [codec like aptX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX) for audio streaming.  These are device (hardware) dependent and have nothing to do with the fike format your audio is stored in.

Comment: aptX is a codec precisely the same fashion as AAC is a codec. I believe you may have inadvertently answered the question, however, if AAC is carried by AD2P.